# SVG filter can't be rendered in React

Tags: javascript, html, svg, reactjs

I am trying to load a SVG filter (in this case `<feGaussianBlur>`) to the graphic element `<rect>` in an web application that uses React(15.0.1). The code looks something similar to this

In component1.js :

```
render(){
   return(
      <defs>
        <filter id='blur'>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <component2 />
   );
}
```

In component2.js:

```
render(){
  <rect x="some_xpos" 
        y="some_ypos"
        height="some_height"
        width="some_width"
        filter="url(#blur)" 
  >
  </rect>
}
```

All these components are to be rendered on the same html page but somehow the filter is not applied when the entire page renders. I have looked into different options:

- option1 : export the svg filter to its own .svg file in a public asset folder and `url()` that using public url. Didn't work because of a Chrome bug [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212)
- option2 : put the `<filter>`  in the main (and the only one) index.html file where the entire app renders. I also put that at the very top wrapped with its own `<svg>` tag. Didn't work.

It seems to me the `<rect>` couldn't figure out where the filter is. I would appreciate any advices on how to debug this or alternative for loading svg filter.

Comment: It would be better if you show the test case that reproduces the error on some services like jsfiddle.net [ https://jsfiddle.net/pmvo81ac/ ]

Comment: thanks for the link, will try to repro it

Comment: I believe it's the lowercase `c` in `<component />`. Works fine with a capital-C `<Component />`: https://jsfiddle.net/pmvo81ac/1/

Comment: I tried that on my app, it still didn't work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't know react, but reading some issues on the github project about xmlns attributes, it seems you need `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2250

Answer (score 1):

SVG elements must be created in the SVG namespace if you're going to directly create them in the DOM. And from what I can see, React does not support that. The workaround, as Kaiddo mentions in the comments is to create the elements as raw innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

the best workaround is to use "style" as follows:

```
<rect x="some_xpos" 
        y="some_ypos"
        height="some_height"
        width="some_width"
        style={ {filter: 'url(#blur)'} }
  >
```